# How many ways are there to place the conference attendees?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

This is my homework question in the discrete mathematics lecture. I couldn't solve the question.
At a conference, there are 3m people that speak English but not Turkish,
3n people that speak Turkish but not English, and 3k people that speak both
English and Turkish; m, n, k ∈ Z+. At the gala dinner, the organizers of the
conference would like to sit everybody at 3-person tables where everybody can
converse with each other. This means we want all three people at every table
to speak a common language.
We don’t care about the order they sit at the table. Only the 3-person groups
are relevant for the purposes of this question.
How many ways are there to place the conference attendees at the dinner?

For the solution, I think that I should calculate the (all cases - (3 people groups contains 2 people that speak only English and 1 people that only speak Turkish) - (3 people groups contains 1 people that speak only English and 2 people that only speak Turkish)) Can you help me for the solution?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to explain where you encountered this question, show what you have attempted, and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

"(all cases - (3 people groups contains 2 people that speak only English and 1 people that only speak Turkish) - (3 people groups contains 1 people that speak only English and 2 people that only speak Turkish)" You missed one case to subtract. 3 people groups where one person is from each of the 3 groups.

Let the groups be T,E ET.
\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline
\text {Set}&\text {Number of combinations}\\
\hline
\text{All Cases}& \binom{3(k+m+n)}{3}\\
\hline
1T2E &\binom{3n}{1}\binom{3m}{2}\\
2T1E &\binom{3n}{2}\binom{3m}{1}\\
1T1E1ET &\binom{3n}{1}\binom{3m}{1}\binom{3k}{1}\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Does the above case not apply to only one table in the conference room? Shouldn't it be generalized for all tables?